# Integrating a loader with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am facing an issue with integrating a loader with d3.js(d3_queue.js).
Currently, I am using a JS hack to show the loading screen which is called on page load, and once the graphs are drawn I am hiding the loader using jQuery.

Code:

```
$(".loader").show();

d3_queue.queue()
  .defer(d3.json, url) 
  .awaitAll(makeCharts);

setTimeout(function() {
  $('.loader').hide();
}, 1000);
```

The problem I am running into is that the loader hides irrespective of the data loaded, i.e. it hides after the 1000ms as per the timeout given.

Comment: Why not call `.hide()` in `makeCharts()` which will be executed once the queue has finished loading all resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module [d3-queue](https://github.com/d3/d3-queue) was designed to explicitly allow for concurrent loading of resources which by nature requires asynchronous processing:

> A queue evaluates zero or more *deferred* asynchronous tasks with configurable concurrency: you control how many tasks run at the same time. When all the tasks complete, or an error occurs, the queue passes the results to your *await* callback.

As you are already providing your callback `makeCharts()` to [`.awaitAll()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-queue#queue_awaitAll) you should also move you hiding functionality into that callback. This will ensure that the loader gets hidden once all resources have finished loading. Your code could look like this:

```
function makeCharts(error, files) {
  // ... process loaded files
  $('.loader').hide();
}

$(".loader").show();
d3_queue.queue()
  .defer(d3.json, url) 
  .awaitAll(makeCharts);
```